# String pool object creation confusion

Tags: string, string-pool

I tried some thing like below :

```
String s1="test5";
String s2="test"+5;
String s3="test"+s1.length();
System.out.println("s1==s2 "+(s1==s2)+"  s2==s3 "+(s2==s3)+" s1==s3 "+ (s1==s3));
```

The output is:

`s1==s2` `true`

`s2==s3` `false`

`s1==s3` `false`

Why `s2` and `s1` are not equal to `s3`? Why a new refrence is being generated for `s3`?

Comment: Thanks @piotrwolkowski

Answer (score 0):

here the `String s2` has always constant value `test5`. But in the `s3` the value is dependent on the `String s1`. if the length of `s1` changes then it will change too thus it is dynamic